# couldn't find "libsupportjni.so" in debug build type

Tags: android, debugging

I have used muiltDex,when I choose debug build type ,this issue must be happened;But when I choose release build type it will not happened;

Answer (score 3):

This seems to a bug in the android Advanced profiling. I am facing the same issue when use a x86_64 emulator or an arm device. You either switch to off Advanced profiling in the Run/Debug configuration or Use a x86 emulator.